# getting the second key value of dict

Tags: python

I would like to get the second value of my dict and multiply it to quantity
is there any way?

```
menuVariable =  chowMenu = {'a': {'Fried Chicken': 99.99}, 'b': {'Chao Fan': 60.99}, 'c': {'Siomai': 45.99}, 'd': {'Chop Suey': 30.00}}
print(" ******** Welcome  to Chowpanda!.********")

def menu(userInput):
    return chowMenu.get(userInput,"Oops! it seems that is not on the menu")
print('\n'.join("{}: {}\n-----------------------".format(k, v) for k, v in chowMenu.items()))
option = input('Please choose your order:')

while  option != 'a' and option != 'b' and option != 'c' and option != 'd' :
    result = print(menu(option))
    option = input('Please choose your order:')
print(menu(option))
quantity = int(input('How many would you like to order?: '))
```

Comment: `print()` doesn't return anything. So `result = print(anything)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "the second value of my dict"? The nested dicts each only have one value.

Comment: I suggest you change your dicts to something like `{"name": "Fried Chicken", "price": 99.99}`

Comment: Can I also calculate the quantity to prices ?  {"name": "Fried Chicken", "price": 99.99}

Answer (score 0):

Change your nested dicts so they have consistent keys, not a different key in each dict. Then you can use `result['price']` to get the price.

You also have other logic problems in the way you print your prompts and call `menu()`.

```
menuVariable = chowMenu = {
    'a': {'name': 'Fried Chicken', 'price': 99.99},
    'b': {'name': 'Chao Fan', 'price': 60.99},
    'c': {'name': 'Siomai', 'price': 45.99},
    'd': {'name': 'Chop Suey', 'price': 30.00}
}
print(" ******** Welcome  to Chowpanda!.********")

def menu(userInput):
    return chowMenu.get(userInput,"Oops! it seems that is not on the menu")

print('\n'.join("{}: {}\n-----------------------".format(k, v['name']) for k, v in chowMenu.items()))
while True:
    option = input('Please choose your order:')
    result = menu(option)
    if result != "Oops! it seems that is not on the menu":
        break
    print(result)

price = result['price']
quantity = int(input('How many would you like to order?: '))
total_price = price * quantity
print(f"Total price is {total_price}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
chicken = menuVariable['a']['Fried Chicken']
newquantity = chicken * 3
print(newquantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to nest your dict like that? Would it not be more efficient to use the following dict?

```
menuVariable1 = {'Fried Chicken': 99.99, 
                'Chao Fan': 60.99, 
                'Siomai': 45.99,
                'Chop Suey': 30.00}
```

or alternatively:

```
menuVariable2 =  {'Appetizers' : {'Salad': 29.99, 'Dumplings': 15.99}
                 'Main Courses' : { 'Fried Chicken': 99.99,
                                    'Chao Fan': 60.99, 
                                    'Siomai': 45.99,
                                    'Chop Suey': 30.00}
                 'Desserts' : {'Ice cream' : 30.00}}
```

Either way, you can use the .get-function to add/multiply values in dicts:

```
menuVariable1.get('Siomai', 0) * 3

menuVariable2['Main Courses'].get('Siomai, 0) * 3
```

Both methods give you the multiple of 3 on Siomai